# Toggle different variables based on click

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two functions One is

```
var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
map.onchange = function() {
tag.innerHTML = maps[this.value][1];
}
```

and the other is

```
var tag2 = document.getElementById('tag2');
map.onchange = function() {
  tag2.innerHTML = maps[this.value][2];
}
```

I also have two links

```
<a href="#" >iframe option one</div></a> | <a href="#">iframe option two</a>
```

I want the standard text to automatticaly be the first function. 
Then when I click on the second link. It will toggle the first fucntion off and the second one on. I have an idea of whats going on. Im just not sure how to impliment it. and I dont want to do it with JQuery. Thank you so much

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    var maps = new Array();
        maps[0] = ["Text A1", "Text A2", "Text A3"];
        maps[1] = ["Text B1", "Text B2", "Text B3"];
        maps[2] = ["Text C1", "Text C2", "Text C3"];
        maps[3] = ["Text D1", "Text D2", "Text D3"];
        maps[4] = ["Text E1", "Text E2", "Text E3"];
        maps[5] = ["Text F1", "Text F2", "Text F3"];
    var map = document.getElementById("complaintType");
    for (i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        var Entry = document.createElement("option");
        Entry.text = maps[i][0];
        Entry.value = i;
        map.add(Entry, null);
    }
var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
map.onchange = function() {
tag.innerHTML = maps[this.value][1];
tag.innerHTML = maps[this.value][2];
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <select name="complaintType" id="complaintType">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    </select>
</form>
<a href="#">Option 1</a> | <a href="#">Option 2</a>
<div id="tag"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're overwriting your functions. You need to assign your functions to variables if you want to call them separately.
Also, you haven't assigned a click event. So pressing either link won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Give both links an ID:

```
<a href="#" id="iframe1">iframe option one</a> | <a href="#" id="iframe2">iframe option two</a>
```

Add an clickevent to both links with the map.onchange in the function:

```
var iframe1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");
var iframe2 = document.getElementById("iframe2");

 iframe1.onclick = function () {
     var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
     map.onchange = function () {
         tag.innerHTML = maps[this.value][1];
     }
 }

 iframe2.onclick = function () {
     var tag2 = document.getElementById('tag2');
     map.onchange = function () {
         tag2.innerHTML = maps[this.value][2];
     }
 }
```

Add the end, for the first time load:

```
var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
map.onchange = function () {
     tag.innerHTML = maps[this.value][1];
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/15fs76yb/1/

Comment: Thank you but even in JSF it didnt work. What I am looking for is that When I click the desired option from the dropdown box, it by default  displays the information that the first link displays (the second column). Then if I click the second link it hides the info that is currently being displayed and displays the information in column three. If I decide to go back to the first link it will display column one again (for the selected option of course) Thank you so much for trying to help me though I really appreciate it.